# Usecases for PowerShell 'MicrosoftTeams' module and 'Microsoft.Graph.Teams'

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Maybe someone can explain to me why there are two separate modules (understanding that the regular module is on top of the graph module anyway) and when to use one or the other.

Comment: Could you please elaoborate on your ask?

Comment: What is there to elaborate,  this looks to me as a clear question: why to modules for the same thing? When to use one of them?

Comment: Both modules have their different features. Could you please check description in answer section

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Teams PowerShell module is a set of cmdlets for managing Teams directly from the PowerShell command line**

The Microsoft Teams PowerShell module includes the following features:

- Uses a single module to manage all aspects of Teams administration,
  including users, teams, policies, and configuration.
- Supports authentication mechanisms such as access tokens and
  credentials.

**Microsoft Graph Teams module is used to perform some basic tasks** like below:

- List users to find the user ID of the logged-in user
- List joinedTeams to get the Teams the user is a member of.
- List channels to get the channels in a Team.
- Send message to send a message to a Team channel.

Ref Doc:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-overview
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0